# Form Param are not receiving with jersey , Weblogic 12 c

Tags: web-services, servlets, jakarta-ee, jersey, weblogic12c

I have my own custom context which contain relevant data required by the jersey service

```
public class TangoContextRC extends ResourceConfig {

    public TangoContextRC() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(TangoContextProvider.class).to(TangoContext.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

code for TangoContextProvider is

```
public class TangoContextProvider implements Factory<TangoContext> {

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Inject
    public TangoContextProvider(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public TangoContext provide() {
        return TangoContextFactory.getInstance(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(TangoContext t) {
    }
}
```

Main problem is in tomcat all form params are correctly receiving and working fine but in **weblogic** version **12 c**  form params are receiving as null.

code for service is

```
    @POST
        @Path("{ruleObjectType}/ruleObject")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public String getRuleObject(@Context TangoContext tangoContext,         
                @FormParam("ruleData") String ruleData,
                @PathParam("ruleObjectType") String ruleObjectType){
//some logic here

    }
```

why form params are not receiving in weblogic?

but i accidentally change position of `@Context tangoContext` to last parameter is start receiving all form params in weblogic as well as tomcat.

Please tell me what is the reason behind this what is key role of this `@Context TangoContext` as a last parameter?

Comment: I've never worked with WebLogic, but I would guess that is something with the JAX-RS implementation. Which JAX-RS implementation are you using on Tomcat? Maybe this link might help: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF299

Comment: @MartijnBurger i am using jersey 2.0 (JAX-RS implementation), same implementation works fine in tomcat but behaves differently on weblogic

Comment: So, it should work on weblogic as well. As it cannot be the code, it must be some configuration.